# Comment savoir si un verbe prend le COI ?

Tags: verbes, compléments

Je suis en train d'apprendre le COI et j'essaie de faire quelques exercices mais je ne sais pas si une phrase doit être formée avec un COI ou pas. Voici les exemples qui me posent problème :

> Carmen était en France depuis un an, sa famille … manquait.

Lui ou la ? Je sais que les verbes avec « à » sont toujours avec COI. Par exemple les verbes comme dire, demander, etc.

Donc, comme manquer est sans « à », j'aurais dit que c'est « sa famille la manque ».

Mais c'est « sa famille lui manque » et je ne comprends pas pourquoi.

La même situation avec la phrase suivante:

> Vous devriez conseiller à Pierre de se calmer. S’il n’arrête pas de raconter ces histoires, cela ... attirera des ennuis.

La réponse correcte est « lui » mais comme attirer n'a pas de « à » ça aurait du être formé avec « l' ».

J'ai trouve cet exercice ici :

https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/pronoms-personnels-cod-ou-coi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Manquer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manquer)* et *[attirer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attirer)* peuvent être utilisés avec un COI ou un COD, leur sens n'est pas le même.

Manquer quelque chose ou quelqu'un, c'est ne pas réussir à l'atteindre.

> Le voyageur a manqué son train, le tireur d'élite a manqué sa cible, Carmen a manqué sa famille car elle est arrivée après leur départ, etc.

Ici, ce n'est pas ce sens de manquer qui est utilisé mais celui de provoquer un sentiment de manque.

> Sa famille manque à Carmen : sa famille lui manque.

L'anglais ne distingue pas ces deux cas et *I missed him* peut vouloir dire aussi bien « il m'a manqué » que « je l'ai manqué ».

Avec *attirer*, le problème est similaire. Ce n'est pas Pierre qui est attiré mais les ennuis :

> Cela attirera des ennuis à Pierre : cela lui attirera des ennuis.

Comment: Merci! I wanted to upvote, too, but do not have enough reputation.